# Collection.shuffle is not working on Map keys nor on the Map values. I have a map within a map. I want to shuffle the map that is the innermost

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, shuffle

for second entry of idAndTags the inner-map is shuffled but not for the first

FIRST APPROACH!

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entryOne : idAndTags.entrySet()) {

    List keys = new ArrayList(entryOne.getValue().keySet());
    System.out.println(keys);
    Collections.shuffle(keys);
    System.out.println(keys);
}
```

SECOND APPROACH!

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entryOne : idAndTags.entrySet()) {
    shufTags = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> tags = entryOne.getValue();
    System.out.println(tags);
    final List<String> vs = new ArrayList<String>(tags.values());
    Collections.shuffle(vs);
    final Iterator<String> vIter = vs.iterator();
    for (String k : tags.keySet())
        shufTags.put(k, vIter.next());
    System.out.println(shufTags);
}
```

Comment: A `HashMap` has **no order**. No amount of shuffling and replacing will convince it otherwise.

Comment: does it mean that java decides by itself what to shuffle and what not to in a HashMap? I ask this because for the idAndTags, the inner map of the second entry is shuffled but not the first

Comment: The order is undefined. Any order your perceive is an implementation detail. There is not even any guarantee that iterating twice of the `Map` will yield that _same_ order.

Comment: @BoristheSpider maybe add an answer

Comment: @BoristheSpiderYou are right! the shuffle returns different results for each execution. however it is consistent in sorting for only one entry of the idAndTags map or none!

Answer (score 1):

[`Map#.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) returns a view of the key set, which doesn't support ordering. Shuffling it has no effect on the map.

You can not change the order of iteration of a `HashMap`, but a `LinkedHashMap` iterates itself in the order of insertion, so you can replace the inner maps with a `LinkedHashMap` and use a shuffled key set to drive the insertion.

Comment: you are right. I am sorry I missed a few lines of code in the last post. however, it is working absolutely fine with this logic that I have given in the "answer"

Answer (score 0):

didn't have a choice, solved it like this... seems to work for me!

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> _idAndTagsShuffled = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entryOne : _idAndTags.entrySet()) {
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList(entryOne.getValue().keySet());
    shuffledMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    do {
        shuffled = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.shuffle(keys);
        for (String key : keys) {
            shuffled.add(key);
        }
        int count = 0;
        isShuffled = false;
        for (String tag : entryOne.getValue().keySet()) {
            if (!tag.equals(shuffled.get(count))) {
                isShuffled = true;
            }
            count++;
        }
    } while (!isShuffled);
    _idAndTagsShuffled.put(entryOne.getKey(), shuffledMap);
}
```